# code desing and error handling: exit program with an error in python

Tags: python, error-handling, exit

I am aware of a few ways to terminate a python script but here I am looking for a good and robust code design (sort of a recommended way to do this).

Most of my code is written in functions that are called from the main function.

I'd like to know what'd be the most recommendable way to stop running a python script/program from a given function (called from main) and give a message error to the user.

Example of my current design (please comment on better practices if have some ideas):

```
import sys


def run_function(x):
    if x == 4:
       print 'error, x cannot be 4'
       sys.exit(0)
    else:
       print 'good x'
    return 0


def main():
    x=4
    run_function(x)
    return 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply print the message, then use `sys.exit()` to end the program. The `argparse` module uses a utility function (adjusted to be more or less stand-alone):

```
def exit(status=0, message=None):
    if message:
        _print_message(message, sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(status)
```

where `_print_message()` writes the message to the designated file object, here `sys.stderr`; basically just using `print`.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, I would suggest that you raise error from the functions and only call the exit in `__main__`.  The message will be passed using raise.  Example:

```
import sys

def run_function(x):
    if x == 4:
        raise ValueError('error, x cannot be 4')
    else:
        print 'good x'
    return 0

def main():
    x=4
    run_function(x)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except ValueError as e:
        sys.exit(e)
```

This way, your function indicate that it received a wrong value, and it is the caller that decide to call a `sys.exit` based on the error.

A little more detail on the [sys.exit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status
>   (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer,
>   zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is
>   considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems
>   require it to be in the range 0-127, and produce undefined results
>   otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific
>   meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally
>   underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax
>   errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object
>   is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is
>   printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. **In particular,
>   sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when
>   an error occurs.**

Comment: Why use `ValueError` when you have `SystemExit`?

Comment: You function should raise what "is wrong" and it's the caller that should make the decision to perform a sys.exit based on error it received.  I will update the answer with this info.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you might want to change your exit code when encountering an error. `exit(0)` normally means the process has terminated without errors. Then why are you returning something in your `run_function`, when you're not even checking it afterwards (in the `else` branch, I mean)?

Other than that, I don't see any questions here to be answered.